# Como criar um executável C# com o .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Estou desenvolvendo um material de introdução à programação usando o .NET Core. Eu li a documentação quanto à criação e execução de projetos para a web, mas não achei nada que aborde como criar um projeto de um aplicativo de console e gerar dele um `.EXE`.

Imaginei que com o `namespace ConsoleApplication` o código geraria um executável, mas na verdade ele cria um `.DLL` que pode ser executado com `dotnet programa.dll`.

O que devo fazer para que o projeto crie um executável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei.

Primeiramente o projeto deve ser criado com `dotnet new -t console`

Como o framework padrão é o `netcoreapp1.0`, quando `dotnet build`for invocado, ele irá compilar `Program.cs` como uma dll. Par que ele compile um executável:

No arquivo `project.json`, deve-se navegar até a opção `"frameworks"`, abrir uma nova linha e incluir `“net461”:{},` (com a vírgula). Remova a opção `"type": "platform",` e acrescente

`"runtimes": {
    "win7-x64":{}
  }`

Após a declaração de `imports`. Regenere o projeto com `dotnet restore`. Depois disso, `dotnet build` compilará `Project.cs` como um executável.

Answer (score -2):

Quando fazes criar novo projeto tens que escolher a opção "Console Application" no tipo de projeto.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta, mas não entendo. Uso o prompt de comando para invocar `dotnet new` na pasta onde habitará o projeto; como escolho Console Application como tipo de projeto?

Comment: Usas o Visual Studio para escrever código?

Comment: Não; para este projeto de material introdutório, a ser usado em laboratórios de informática com poucos recursos, vou usar o Visual Studio Code como editor. Queria usar uma tag `vscode`, mas ainda não tenho reputação suficiente neste StackOverflow para isto.

Comment: Removi a tag visual-studio, não guarda relação com o assunto. Mas também não adicionei vscode, pois a pergunta não trata das IDEs, e sim de como criar a aplicação executável e console, se entendi bem (creio que uma boa resposta não deva apresentar solução que funcione somente em uma IDE).

Comment: Completamente ridiculo. Esta situação tem tudo a ver com o tipo de IDE que tens obviamente. Se trabalhares com o Visual Studio é de uma maneira, com o VS Code é outra, é ridiculo uma resposta certa a esta pergunta e que não indique que com o Visual Studio Community (Gratis) é só clikar new console application e no outro não. E responde à pergunta, ele é que não foi explicito. Mas abandono a pergunta já que se calhar a única que responde à questão sem depender do IDE é "Fazendo")